# "It's not to be" meaning here

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the Seinfeld series, Jerry says:

> Well, birthdays are merely symbolic of how another year has gone by and
>   how little we've grown. No matter how desperate we are that someday a better
>   self will emerge, with each flicker of the candles on the cake, **we know it's not to be**, that for the rest of our sad, wretched pathetic lives, this is who we are
>   to the bitter end. Inevitably, irrevocably; happy birthday? No such thing.

I can't get the verb "be". Does it have any thing that's dropped?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"It is not to be" is an idiom meaning "It is not supposed/intended/destined to happen". Sometimes this just means "It is not going to happen" with a connotation of regret or disappointment.

Comment: Thank you. Would you provide the resource?

Comment: I've looked it up but I couldnt find this idiom in my dictionary. What dictionary should I check?

Comment: I'd say this is a variation of "[meant to be](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/meant+to+be)", which is a much more commonly seen idiom

Comment: [not to be](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/not_to_be) reference

Comment: Actually, this "set phrase" is far more likely to occur in the *past tense* form: *He had been expecting [whatever], **but it was not to be***.

Comment: @FirstLastname: In the *present tense* mode, you could reasonably assume an element of ***intention***. But per previous comment, that's not very common anyway. I don't naturally assume any allusion to God / Fate / other interested parties thwarting expectations in the past tense usage. It just means the *writer* knows already that something doesn't lie in the future of his narrative reference time, and wishes to convey that to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

"it's not to be" in this context means that he is not going to become a better person, saying he desperately wants to become a better version but it's not to be. That is,he won't become a better person, no matter how many years go by. Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe edit your answer to match the wording of the  original quote.  ... 'Desperate... for a better self to emerge,...,we know its not to be'  The author believes that themselves (and by extension of their own pessimistic view through the use of 'we' meaning everyone ) cannot improve themselves.  If something is to happen (a better self will emerge) it 'will be' - the author believes it will not ('its not to be').